# How to load offline self-hosted font in React and Material Ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to load self hosted fonts, i have added everything but still not working

```
import React from "react";
import { createTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const proximanovaBold = {
    fontFamily: 'Proximanova',
    src: `url('./fonts/proximanova-bold.otf') format('otf')`,
    fontWeight: 'normal'
}
const proximanovaRegular = {
    fontFamily: 'Proximanova',
    src: `url('./fonts/proximanova-regular.otf') format('otf')`,
    fontWeight: 'normal'
}
const proximanovaLight = {
    fontFamily: 'Proximanova',
    src: `url('./fonts/proximanova-light.otf') format('otf')`,
    fontWeight: 'normal'
}
const proximanovaThin = {
    fontFamily: 'Proximanova',
    src: `url('./fonts/proximanova-thin.otf') format('otf')`,
    fontWeight: 'normal'
}
const proximanovaSemiBold = {
    fontFamily: 'Proximanova',
    src: `url('./fonts/proximanova-semibold.otf') format('otf')`,
    fontWeight: 'normal'
}
const proximanovaExtraBold = {
    fontFamily: 'Proximanova',
    src: `url('./fonts/proximanova-extra-bold.otf') format('otf')`,
    fontWeight: 'normal'
}
const theme = createTheme({
    typography: {
        fontFamily: 'Proximanova',
        body1: {
            fontFamily: 'proximanovaThin',
            fontSize: 18
        },
        button: {
            fontFamily: 'proximanovaBold',
            fontSize: 14
        },
        body2: {
            fontFamily: 'proximanovaRegular',
            fontSize: 14
        },
        h1: {
            fontFamily: 'proximanovaExtraBold',
            fontSize: 14
        },
        h2: {
            fontFamily: 'proximanovaBold',
            fontSize: 14
        },
        h3: {
            fontFamily: 'proximanovaSemiBold',
            fontSize: 14
        },
        h4: {
            fontFamily: 'proximanovaRegular',
            fontSize: 14
        },
        h5: {
            fontFamily: 'proximanovaLight',
            fontSize: 14
        },
        h6: {
            fontFamily: 'proximanovaThin',
            fontSize: 14
        }
    },
    overrides: {
        MuiCssBaseline: {
            '@global': {
                '@font-face': [proximanovaRegular, proximanovaBold, proximanovaLight, proximanovaExtraBold, proximanovaThin, proximanovaSemiBold]
            }
        }
    }
})

export { theme, MuiThemeProvider }

<Button
      onClick={handleClick}
      color="primary"
      variant={type}
      disabled={disabled}
    >
      <Typography variant="h2">{title}</Typography>
    </Button>
```